# How to judge bmp pictures from clipboard whether they are same using wxpython?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

Function that I want to realize: 
when the bmp picture get from clipboard is changed, refresh window. If not, nothing will be done.

Question that I meet: 
every time my program goes into function UpdateMsgShownArea(), self.oldBmp will be diff with self.bmp, but I have already let self.oldBmp = self.bmp if they are different, and it prints "111111". While next time the program goes into UpdateMsgShownArea(), self.oldBmp will be diff with self.bmp again. It confuses me.

[image: my print message image]

code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx
import os, sys

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# main window
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(600,480))
        self.panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.CreateStatusBar() # A StatusBar in the bottom of the window

        # Setting up the menu.
        filemenu= wx.Menu()

        # wx.ID_ABOUT and wx.ID_EXIT are standard ids provided by wxWidgets.
        menuAbout = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About"," Information about this program")
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"E&xit"," Terminate the program")

        # Creating the menubar.
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File") # Adding the "filemenu" to the MenuBar
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.

        # Set events.
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)

        self.Show(True)

    def OnAbout(self,e):
        # A message dialog box with an OK button. wx.OK is a standard ID in wxWidgets.
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog( self, "A small text editor", "About Sample Editor", wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal() # Show it
        dlg.Destroy() # finally destroy it when finished.

    def OnExit(self,e):
        self.Close(True)  # Close the frame.

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# main panel
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        # shared path boxsizer, DirPickerCtrl is alternative and better realization for textCtrl + btn
        sharedPathStaticText = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Shared Dir:')
        self.sharedPathTextCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, 'Please choose a dir', style = wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_RICH)
        sharedPathBtn = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Browse', name = 'Shared dir button')


        box1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        box1.Add(sharedPathStaticText, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        box1.Add(self.sharedPathTextCtrl, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 5) # proportion = 1, border = 5
        box1.Add(sharedPathBtn, 0)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpen, sharedPathBtn)

        # local path boxsizer
        localPathStaticText = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Local Dir:   ')
        self.localPathTextCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, 'Please choose a dir', style = wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_RICH)
        localPathBtn = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Browse', name = 'local dir button')

        box2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        box2.Add(localPathStaticText, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        box2.Add(self.localPathTextCtrl, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 5) # proportion = 1, border = 5
        box2.Add(localPathBtn, 0)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpen, localPathBtn)

        # message show area
        messageShowStaticText = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Sync info shown area:   ')

        box5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        box5.Add(messageShowStaticText, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT)

        # size (200,200) don't take effect
        #msgShowAreaID = wx.NewId()
        #print msgShowAreaID
        self.msgShowArea = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1, size = (200,200), style = wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)

        box3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        box3.Add(self.msgShowArea, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 10)

        # sync ctrl buttons
        stopSyncBtn = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Stop Sync', name = 'Stop Sync button')
        resumeSyncBtn = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Resume Sync', name = 'Resume Sync button')

        box4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        box4.Add(stopSyncBtn, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.RIGHT, 20)
        box4.Add(resumeSyncBtn, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.LEFT, 20)

        # sizer
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(box1, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(box2, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(box5, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(box3, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(box4, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 10)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)

        # clipboard
        self.clip = wx.Clipboard()
        self.x = wx.BitmapDataObject()
        self.bmp = None
        self.oldBmp = None

        self.msgShowArea.Bind(wx.EVT_IDLE, self.UpdateMsgShownArea)
        self.msgShowArea.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def OnOpen(self, e):
        """ Open a file"""
        button = e.GetEventObject()
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a dir", "", wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()

            if button.GetName() == 'Shared dir button':
                self.sharedPathTextCtrl.SetValue(path)
            if  button.GetName() == 'local dir button':
                self.localPathTextCtrl.SetValue(path)
        dlg.Destroy()

    def UpdateMsgShownArea(self, e):
        print "UpdateMsgShownArea"
        self.clip.Open()
        self.clip.GetData(self.x)
        self.clip.Close()
        self.bmp = self.x.GetBitmap()
        if self.oldBmp == self.bmp:
            print "same pic"
            return
        else:
            print "diff pic"
            self.oldBmp = self.bmp
            if  self.oldBmp == self.bmp:
                print "111111"
            else:
                print "222222"

        print "abcd"
        #self.Refresh()
        #self.msgShowArea.Refresh()

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        if self.bmp:
            dc = wx.PaintDC(self.msgShowArea)
            dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 20, 20, True)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame(None, "EasySync")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I have solve this problem by myself. Use "wx.Bitmap.ConvertToImage().GetData()" to transfer bitmap to an image then get raw python buffer, then compare the buffer. It seems Bitmap can not use "=" to assign value.

Comment: Your can always post your solution as an answer to your own question. This will enable others to see how you resolved the problem in the future. After 24 hours you can then select your own answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert bitmap to image and then compare images can solve this problem.

```
        self.clip.GetData(self.bmpObj)
        self.bmp = self.bmpObj.GetBitmap()  # bitmap
        self.Img = self.bmp.ConvertToImage().GetData()  # convert bmp to image
        isDrawBmp = True

        if CLIP_TYPE_IMAGE == self.lastClipType:
            if self.oldImg == self.Img:    # compare images
                #print "same pic"
                #return
                isDrawBmp = False
            else:
                #print "diff pic"
                self.oldImg = self.Img

        else:
            self.oldImg = self.Img
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for clipboard change notifications in wxWidgets, unfortunately. Under MSW it would be relatively simple to add it, but I'm less sure about the other platforms.

In any case, right now your only choice is to poll the clipboard for changes, i.e. set up a timer and check the clipboard contents every time it fires. This is ugly and inefficient, but should work.